# How to open an Excel file from MS Access?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to open an Excel file, in MS Acesss, I select using the `FileDialogFilePicker`. However, when I select the Excel file the "Open" prompt turns to "Ok" and I am unable to open it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Below is the working code that selects the file.

```
Dim f As FileDialog
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
f.Show
```

Thank you!

Comment: you need to create a reference to Excel. `Dim xl as Excel.Application | Set xl = New Excel.Application | xl.Visible = True xl.Workbooks.Open(f)` make sure to have the reference for Excel checked in Tools > References or use late binding.

Comment: Thanks again. That worked great. I've posted the revised code.

Comment: @Chris2015 you can post that code in an answer and accept your own answer. It brings a nice resolution within the Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the final code:

```
Dim f As FileDialog, str As String
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
f.Show
str = f.SelectedItems(1)

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open (str)
```